# GDB TUI: Scroll assembly view above current instruction?

Tags: assembly, gdb

I've only just started using GDB recently, but I'm super impressed by it. No wonder it's the de-facto debugger for many users. One minor annoyance that I've found, though, is that I find myself unable to scroll above the current instruction in the TUI assembly view. I can scroll up and down just fine so long as display buffer is underneath the current instruction.

Other than something like `x/20i [address]` (which kind of defeats the purpose of a scrollable window) or altering the memory with a jump and setting a subsequent breakpoint, is there any way to tell the TUI assembly view to look at another location that might be above (lower memory than) the current instruction?

Edit: This only seems to happen when attached to an already running process, not when using gdb to launch the process. Sometimes I can scroll up until the current instruction, other times I can't scroll up t all.

Comment: Lacking any other answers, you can look into using one of gdb front-ends, which will allow you to scroll disassembly (among other things). See here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends

Comment: Thanks! Using `cgdb` resolved my problem!

Comment: I've raised an issue for this, as it's driving me mad: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26024

Comment: Remark: The bug linked above points out that the bug happens when the program crashed with SIGSEGV, **and** the bug is fixed in gdb 10, so upgrading is an option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be some kind of issue with scrolling assembly in gdb tui like you explain, but a simple workaround exists.

So, first enable tui and disassembly view by pressing ctrl+x ctrl+a. Then show disassembly view by entering layout asm or something similar.

Now that windows should let you scroll with keys or mouse, but if it stops (which for me sometimes happens at beginning of some function) enter the usual disassemble command and disassembly view will update to that location.

Example:

> disass main
>   disass 0x1234

Comment: I guess it'll work. The only problem is that the 'disassemble' command doesn't work with this particular binary -- no debug symbols. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I'm guessing that it's because the length of an instruction (in bytes) is variable -- so disassembling "backwards" would require it to "guess" how many bytes the previous instruction was.

Comment: Instead of "disassemble" you can use x/i.

Comment: Even without debug symbols, you can do something like `dis $pc-50, $pc+50`

Comment: Doesn't work for me =( disass  complains about the lac of function at a given address.

Comment: @DanM. you need to specify a range... `disassemble $rip-50, $rip+50` worked for me (just -50 didn't). To specify an absolute addres for setting a breakpoint for example I also need to add a `*`... like `b *0x12345678`.

Comment: I found `disassemble $rip` is a nice short command that works to recover the tui asm display after scrolling down off the end of a function without having to remember any code symbols to reference.

Answer (score 7):

I've found a small hack. If you're in `layout asm` mode and you can't scroll to the current instruction you can execute command `layout split` and then `layout asm` and the first line will be the current one.

Comment: IIRC, `frame 0` can work to return to the current instruction if you've scrolled down and can't scroll back up?  It's unfortunately that GDB won't scroll back to a known starting point like the current RIP, if not inside a function with a symbol.

Comment: Neither of these worked for me, but `disassemble $rip` recovered the asm display back into the current function.